# Proving certain function is a measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ a measurable space. Let$\mu:\Sigma \to \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$ be the set function that satisfies:

(a)$A,B \in \Sigma$ and $A \cap B=\emptyset \implies \mu(A \cup B)=\mu(A)+\mu(B)$

(b) $A_n \in \Sigma (n \in \mathbb N)$ and $A_n \searrow \emptyset \implies  \lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n)=0$.

I got stuck at trying to show sigma-additivty, I'll write what I've done up to now:

By (a) one can prove $\mu$ is monotone, so $0 \leq\mu(\emptyset)=\mu(\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty} A_k) \leq \mu(A_k) \implies \mu(\emptyset) \leq \inf_{k \in \mathbb N} \mu(A_k)$ for all $k$. Since $(A_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}$ is decreasing, then $(\mu(A_k))_{k \in \mathbb N}$ is also decreasing, so $\inf_{k \in \mathbb N} \mu(A_k)=\lim_{k \to \infty} \mu(A_k)=0$, it follows $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.

Given a sequence $(A_k)_{k \in \mathbb N}$ of disjoint sets, I want to show $\mu(\cup_{k \in \mathbb N} A_k)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_k)$.By induction one can prove $\mu$ is finitely additive. We have $$\sum_{k=1}^N \mu(A_k)=\mu(\cup_{k=1}^N A_k)$$$$ \leq \mu(\cup_{k \in \mathbb N} A_k)$$ If we let $N \to \infty$, then $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(A_k)=\mu(\cup_{k=1}^N A_k) \leq  \mu(\cup_{k \in \mathbb N} A_k)$$

I would appreciate any suggestions or hints to show the other inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good idea would be to consider the sets $B_n = \bigcup_{k=n}^{+\infty}A_k$.

Comment: I can see that the $B_n$'s are going to form an increasing sequence of sets, but I don't see what can I do with it.

Comment: It is not increasing, but you have the property (b) on decreasing sets.